# Segfault when using doParallel with Rcpp module

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to use `Rcpp module` with `doParallel`. However, it seems that they are not compatible. This is a example would produce segfault. I have tried similar thing with the `R built-in reference class` and it works fine.

```
require(doParallel)
require(Rcpp)
require(inline)

inc = '
using namespace Rcpp; class Uniform { public:
    Uniform(double min_, double max_) : min(min_), max(max_) {}
    NumericVector draw(int n) const {
        RNGScope scope;
        return runif( n, min, max ); }
    double min, max;
};
double uniformRange( Uniform* w) { return w->max - w->min;
}
RCPP_MODULE(unif_module) {
    class_<Uniform>( "Uniform" )
    .constructor<double,double>()
    .field( "min", &Uniform::min )
    .field( "max", &Uniform::max )
    .method( "draw", &Uniform::draw )
    .method( "range", &uniformRange )
    ;
}
'
fx <- cxxfunction(signature(), plugin="Rcpp", include=inc)
unif_module <- Module("unif_module", getDynLib(fx))
Uniform <- unif_module$Uniform

registerDoParallel(2)

myObjs = foreach(i=1:2) %dopar% {
    u <- new( Uniform, 0, 10 )
    u$draw( 10L )
    u
}
myObjs
```

Followed by the comment of Dirk, I tried to use Package with doParallel, but I still get segfault.

```
library(Rcpp)
require(doParallel)
Rcpp.package.skeleton( "MyPackage", module = TRUE )
install.packages("MyPackage", repos=NULL)
library(MyPackage)
NumEx = Module("NumEx", PACKAGE="MyPackage")
Num = NumEx$Num

registerDoParallel(2)
foreach(i=1:2) %dopar% {
    obj = new(Num)
    obj
}
```

FYI, the ordinary Reference class works flewlessly with doParallel.

```
require(doParallel)

myClass = setRefClass("myClass",
    fields = c("a"),
    methods = list(
        show = function(){cat("hello\n")}
    )
)

registerDoParallel(2)
objs = foreach(i=1:2) %dopar% {
    obj = new("myClass")
    obj$a=i
    obj
}
objs[[1]]$a
```

Comment: Your title should be edited to something like 'Segfault when using doParallel with inline-compiled code'. Rcpp is not at fault per se, it's how you use it.

Comment: i changed the title as suggested.

Comment: Try installing 'MyPackage' on each worker _before_ spawning the nodes and instantiating.

Comment: And the name is still Dirk not Dick.

Comment: sorry for the misspelling. Trust me, I know it is "Dirk"..who doesn't know you? :p

Comment: Ok, no sweat.  FWIW I still type it as Drik about 1/3 of the time ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a 'Rcpp reference class'.

You are compiling a local extension via inline, and then shipping that (with its memory location) to the workers. That can't work and is known not to work -- they will access some random memory content.

For parallel work in this fashion, you need to build the extension by each worker --- which is why the general recommendation *always* is to use a package, and have each worker load the package.

Comment: I think it may not be related to inline or package. I am trying to use Package with doParallel, and segfault again. See the updated post.

Comment: It may just be that Modules-generated objects cannot be shared.  I have to think about that -- it is not something I have tried I think.  These objects may be local to the session, and do not survive a `fork()` call.  You may want to post this on `rcpp-devel`.